# Spring unauthorized request despite having .permitAll()

Tags: spring, security, authentication, spring-security

Here's the configuration class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${allowed-origins}")
    String[] allowedOrigins;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); // To be able to see h2 console
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/transform-user").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().realmName("RDF-TRANSFORMER")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(allowedOrigins));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(("*")));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }

}
```

You can see I have all the requests except the transform-user call enabled to not authenticated users.

But when I call the endpoint /api/identity I get this response:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-05-29T10:35:47.058+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/api/identity"}
```

Edit: I just saw I get this error when deploying the app:

```
  [2020.05.29 12:44:21] (Coverage): Error during class instrumentation: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Class not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The security configuration order is not correct. Try below one -

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); // To be able to see h2 console
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/transform-user").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().realmName("RDF-TRANSFORMER")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```